# Object field in {% url %}

Tags: django, django-templates

Is it possible to insert into {% url %} field from queryset record?

e. g.

```
{% url queryset[0].field %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I viewed django source and reach the conclusion that what I want to do is not possible, so I made it other way. In view for every record from query set I added new field url:

```
for q in queryset:
    q.url = reverse(q.field_with_url_name)
```

I think the simplest way

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible, but square brackets are not valid syntax *anywhere* in Django's templating language. This is very clearly documented.

This would work:

```
{% url queryset.0.field %}
```

Comment: Yes, I can`t use queryset[0], I made a mistake when a was writing question, but I can`t use your method either. I think when you will use queryset.0.field django will search "queryset.0.field" name in urls.